# I cannot ensure that alerts mui display under each other, instead they appear on top of each other (so they cover each other)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, alert

```
const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([]);

const showAlert = (success: boolean, message: string) =>
    {
        const newAlert: AlertInfo = {
            success,
            message,
        };
        setAlerts((prevAlerts) => [...prevAlerts, newAlert]);
    };

<Box style={{ position: 'absolute', top: 115, zIndex: 9999, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column-reverse', height: '400px', gap: '8px' }}>
            {alerts.map((alert, index) => (
                <Box key={index}>
                    <Alert
                        severity={alert.success ? 'success' : 'error'}
                        onClose={() => closeAlert(index)}
                    >
                        {alert.message}
                    </Alert>
                </Box>
            ))}
        </Box>
```

The idea is to display Alerts under each other, so they dont interfere with other elements in dom. Instead they appear on top of each other (so they cover each other)

I attempted to manage alerts without using an array, displayed them with and without flex, and tried to position a box that wraps the alert relatively. I adjusted its top property dynamically depending on the index, but nothing had any effect on the alert behavior. They still appear on top of each other.

If I don't use position: absolute, alerts appear under the element I'm trying to delete. These elements are presented inside cells of a table, resulting in undesirable behavior; alerts should appear on top of the page.

Help me please i m stuck :)